# PHP How to stop Chrome loading a page twice

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

> Note: I have updated and rewritten my question to try and solve this issue point by point. Cheers.

I have a problem and I'm not immediately sure how to go about resolving it.

I have been building a secured login system on a HTTPS server (with a grade of "A" by SSL-labs, if that's worth anything ), and it works fine, however today it is refusing to log me in, with some debugging I have found something very odd (in my view).

I have some serious issues with session handling on the website, the different pages use the same session data (of course) and the same session /cookie settings, and they pass the information between each other correctly, **BUT** the behaviour of my browser appears to be as if there are two browsers visiting the same websites, using the same session data.

Symptoms - Because I have been having inconsistencies with page generated session content (unique hash token) not fitting the same data saved in the login form (as a `$_POST` value), I was finding that as there is only one line in the whole site that sets the value of the session, this line must be running twice. So I set a counter value in the session, on the form page as `session['counter']`. each time the page loads, the counter +1's. My problem is specifically with this:

**Login page:**

```
Opens page,  
session hash-string is generated and saved to the post form.
session counter = counter + 1;
Form is filled in.
```

**Login auth' page:**

```
fails to verify the posted hash-string is the same as the session hash
 string, despite there being no other cause for the session values to
 change (well there must be, but I can't see it!)
```

But, then going back to the *Login Page* I see that the counter = last value + 2! Also, the counter value *recorded on the session file saved on the server* is always +1 to the value displayed on the login page.

Some images:

[image]

Login Form Page: Please note that this is above the HTML output and is the ***last place on the code where any SESSION data is edited***.

Output :

[image]

Please note the number relating to the counter in image 1.

[image]

My session file, this file relates to this specific browser session and only 1 session file as I am the only browser on the site.

[image]

The string `CheckDrop` is the hash value to compare but the counter is at **12** rather than 11, which is displayed in image 2 above.

- My site is HTTPS authed although this work is on a subdomain.
- This issue has been happening for the last 3 hours but *inconsistently*, it magically worked for about 40 minutes earlier today (just before posting this post). but I had done nothing I could see as changing the environment.
- I have previously compared phpinfo data and session setup data it all looks correct at point of browser output. It does not seem to be caused by my settings.
- It happens on different browsers on my PC.

### Further Work

After spending hours debugging and working through this, it appears to be a browser issue. I have renamed the pages (one page was called index while it was not defined in .htaccess as the directory listing page which may have *possibly* caused a browser to open it twice).

I have cleared all associated data: sessions / database records / browser history, and have come across something:

Firefox now logs in as expected, the counter is count+1 and the login works, however on Chrome the exact same log in on the same pages does not work and the browser appears to load twice, the `counter = counter + 2`. Chrome also leaves two records in the database at each load rather than the expected one.

Chrome version 45.0.24
Firefox version 42.0

Page double counts and runs script twice on **Safari** and **Chrome**. On Firefox, Opera and MSIE it works as intended.

**Any ideas why this is occurring**?

**How can I go about trying to solve this problem?**

Comment: "with a salty topping"...I've always seen everyone saying not to use your own salt with the standard `password_hash` function.

Comment: it is not a hash salt, it's a salt in the string that is turned into a hash

Comment: So let me make sure I get this: you're hashing the user-agent and IP and then putting them in a hidden input of a form?  They're going to both come back in the request so you'd be better off checking that the ip and user-agent on the request headers match what's in the session. The way you're doing it (unless I misunderstood), if someone intercepted the html they could imitate another person's ip by presenting the hash in a post parameter.

Comment: it's a token CSRF check, @developerwjk -

Comment: the values are compared to the current browser, but the values in the session are also compared to the values in the POST. They are not mutually exclusive comparisons. @developerwjk

Comment: But shouldn't a CSRF be a token that expires after one use? The hash of the user-agent and ip will last as long as the session. I don't think it makes sense to reuse the user-agent and ip for this.

Comment: possibly, but there are other uses for this value and it's an identifying hash, that's all. But the value of the hash is not important to the factor that session variables are being populated without that population being coded. How can I go about finding how this is occurring?

Comment: I have rewritten the question with clarifying images and a specific point to address, cheers.

Comment: any ideas for solving this?

Comment: curiously, with reference to the anwser below by RiccardoC, the only browser this issue doesn't appear on is MSIE11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original issue was caused by the naming of the webpages, there was a webpage named "index.php" but this page was NOT the index, instead "loggedIn.php" was the index page for the site, as defined in `.htaccess`

Having an index.php page that was not an index seemed to confuse a lot of browsers. This [part of] the issue was resolved by renaming all the pages and setting an index.php page that used PHP headers to redirect people to the suitable page (based on if logged in or not) .

The issue remained with Chrome and Safari.

After a long time reading lots of issues about Chrome, the solution was frankly pathetic,

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810

This link lists various issues relating to this problem of Chrome double loading, if certain markup elements are not present. As my page above are very simple, there wasn't a lot that applied, but Google Chrome will silently request the `favicon.ico` file and then if it doesn't find it, will reload the page but only output the first page (from Chrome memory cache).

This is an epically stupid bug in Chrome that has cost me most of a day. Safari still persists in loading the PHP script twice,

Comment: I want to give you multiple votes. You saved my life. Favicon was culprit in my case too.

Comment: Thanks for your investigative perseverance. Would upvote twice. Hmm. Maybe I should upvote with chrome? My setting was: An index.php that writes a file. With fopen("f.txt", "w") all dandy. With fopen("f.txt", "a"): Double output with fwrite() exclusively under chrome. Had to add an html-scaffold and a favicon with <link rel="icon">.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late to the party, but I've found another reason why this was happening for me. I created the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    error_log('Loaded');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Even this minimal page was loading twice, but only in Chrome, so I started investigating, and found [Mendeley Web Importer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mendeley-web-importer/dagcmkpagjlhakfdhnbomgmjdpkdklff) Chrome extension to be causing this behaviour. Simply disabling it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose your problem is with Internet Explorer... I had the same problem and I discovered, with incredible surprise and shock, that internet explorer 10 will send a different "user agent" value, from request to request.

When I saw it for the first time I was really impressed by the absurdity of the fact, but that's completely sure. I tested it very deeply and you cannot trust the Internet Explorer "user agent" string to be the same from request to request.

I had to remove that string from the hashing login string

Comment: I am not using internet explorer

Comment: php does not have browser compatibility issues because it is not a language that browsers read, and the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` element is severely un-trustable

Comment: I had another matter with ajax (my salt was dynamic but the ajax request changed it and thus I lost the connection). By the way, I should try to save in the session var all the "hasing components" to be sure there isn't any strange character, space or other thing that make your final hash wrong

Comment: If that's the case, then Internet Explorer 10 is simply to be banned by all web applications that care about security. But I really doubt that it is the case. You probably have a virus or something.

Comment: I can ensure you I've not a virus. I tested it with different PCs in my company. This is my job, I do not throw accusation like this because I like too. I can ensure you that IE 10, until 3 month ago (when I completely remove any "http_user_agent" use from all my company application) was completely untrustable. I'm not the first to be picked by this absurdity

Comment: Maybe your whole company has a virus. Or they've installed some squirly software that's messing with the user-agents in IE.