# PHP) Both setcookies are being triggered in if else statement

Tags: php, setcookie

I have this code

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["counter"])){
    setcookie("counter",0,(time()+(60*60*24*365)));
    echo "he";
}else{
    setcookie("counter",($_COOKIE["counter"]+=5),(time()+(60*60*24*365)));
    echo "eh";
}
?>
```

I thought this code should work so:
when the page is loaded, check cookie counter. If cookie counter doesn't exist create cookie with name counter and give them value 0. If it exists, instead of creating a new cookie, just add 5 to counter.

But when I open the php file, I get this result

[image]

I can't understand why is it happening so?

echo "eh" is not triggered but both setcookies are triggered ? how can this happen? Shouldn't it be 0 instead ?

Comment: And where is this code in relation to your other code

Comment: did you clear all the existing cookies and then try running the application, might be an old cookie exists already , or you might have code elsewhere that is setting the cookie again.

Comment: Does it ever get to 10,15,20....

Comment: It is impossible for both the `if` and the `else` to be trigered in the same run of the same script. What is happening is that the script is running multiple times with different results or that multiple calls are being made from the same device to that page URI.

Comment: There are various edge cases that can cause this, for instance, previous versions (maybe still current) of Google Chrome will try and look for a favicon on each website it loads but if no `favicon.ico` file is found, the page actually can be loaded twice in the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly , no I tried refeshing site and it shows 10 maybe just for 0.01 secs and jumps to 15. Same when I refresh again. shows 20 just for 0.01 secs and jumps automatically to 25.

Comment: @Saravanan so u mean for example if I have cookie with name counter in another php file, that cookie can also affect the result?

Comment: Works just fine here, when the code you show is the only code in the script

Comment: @RiggsFolly I figured out it happens just in chrome, in firefox it works without problem..

Comment: ALso works perfectly on Chrome

Comment: Also in new Edge

Comment: Maybe you have cached JS code that is reloading something?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Then I don't know what is the problem. I created a new cookie in else statement, setcookie("counter2",5,(time()+(60*60*24*365)));, and chrome creates it .  When it shouldn't create it. Firefox doesn't do that..

Comment: @Martin favicon.ico is already installed with xampp and it is inside htdocs folder, I did copy paste it but doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @gamelover , my (old) question on this subject can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762054/php-how-to-stop-chrome-loading-a-page-twice/61189592#61189592 maybe this will give some more views as to causes and diagnosis?

Comment: @Martin thank you for your comments, but it had nothing to do with that. The culprit was an extension which I installed haha

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The culprit was an extension which I installed. I can't tell the name but for you who has same problem now/future you can try to disable extensions and find out which one causes the problem

Comment: why can't you name the extension?

Comment: @Martin just don't want make any problems future. That's why I don't want to leave name of extension

Comment: well then the answer is worthless because saying "it's an extension" adds no clarity to the issue, or diagnosis. *shrug*.